# What's the height of the Android Toolbar?

Tags: android

What is the height of the Android `Toolbar` introduced in Lollipop? It's a quite simple question but I haven't found an answer here except for the `ActionBar`; but it has a different height.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

The `Toolbar` (if not extended) has the height of:

- `56dp` (default)
- `48dp` (landscape)
- `64dp` (sw600dp; i.e. tablet)

The `Toolbar` is higher than the pre-lollipop `ActionBar`; it was `48dp` by default, `40dp` in landscape and `56dp` in sw600dp.

And to retrieve the height of the Toolbar in XML, just use

`?android:attr/actionBarSize`

or if you're using the AppCompat library this

`?attr/actionBarSize`

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that AppCompat library using different value.

Comment: And what if we would like to use "?android:attr/actionBarSize" in a file "dimens.xml" like this for instance:
  <dimen name="toolbarHeight">?android:attr/actionBarSize</dimen>

Comment: difference b/w in `?android:attr/actionBarSize` & `?attr/actionBarSize`..?

Answer (score 18):

Call this method to get the value programmatically:

```
public int getToolBarHeight() {
    int[] attrs = new int[] {R.attr.actionBarSize};
    TypedArray ta = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs);
    int toolBarHeight = ta.getDimensionPixelSize(0, -1);
    ta.recycle();
    return toolBarHeight;
}
```