# How can I recreate toolbar when rotation occurs

Tags: android, android-toolbar

Reading [this so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30570904/whats-the-height-of-the-android-toolbar) one can see that toolbar uses different heights on landscape vs portrait mode.

But when `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` is specified, toolbar height remains static according to the orientation in which the activity was first created and won't change when rotating the device.

How can I work this around? I'm thinking that either I should resize the toolbar inside `onConfigurationChanged()` method or I should destroy and recreate the toolbar and let it get its default height from scratch. I actually like this 2nd way better but I don't know how to do any of these so any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: you should destroy and recreate the toolbar and let it get its default height from scratch

Comment: Yeap but how can I do that?

Comment: create different layout for portrait and landscape, and define toolbar height as you want

Answer (score 0):

to get rotation event:

```
    @Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

to resize layout:

First you have to declare the layout u wanna resize:

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.yourId);
```

And resize:

```
 rl.getLayoutParams().height = 100;  // replace 100 with your dimensions
    rl.getLayoutParams().width = 100;
```