# Default height of toolbar with menu icons

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

What is the default height of the android toolbar if it contains a menu with icons?

If I use

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize" />
```

then it looks cut-off like this

[image: toolbar]

If I use

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

it works correctly. But it flickers for a moment when initializing the Activity, because it starts smaller and gets adjusted a few miliseconds later.

How to set the correct height right from the beginning?

### Update

The full XML looks like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"    
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"    
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MyActivity" >
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/myToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            android:elevation="@dimen/elevation"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The menu file looks like this

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      tools:context=".MyActivity" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_save"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_save"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

In my Activity `onCreate()` method I do this

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mine);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.myToolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the height of the Android Toolbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30570904/whats-the-height-of-the-android-toolbar)

Comment: No, that solves **not** my problem. Have you even read the duplicate you refer to?

Comment: Can you provide full layout xml?

Comment: @Mehmed: I added the layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **actionBarSize** is correct approach but it looks like your `Toolbar` is under `StatusBar`.

To avoid drawing under the Android `StatusBar` you should disable `fitsSystemWindows` for your root layout (`CoordinatorLayout`). If you want to read more, check out [this article](https://medium.com/google-developers/why-would-i-want-to-fitssystemwindows-4e26d9ce1eec).

---

For others, if `android:fitsSystemWindows="false"` doesn't help you can check if the problem is connected with a transparency of status bar - look for `android:windowTranslucentStatus`, `android:statusBarColor` in the project.

Even if you didn't set any of these settings by yourself, these could come from default Android Studio template.

Comment: I did not customize any of those and the last tip did not work as expected. It adds a padding but still cuts off the icons. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Maybe I add the toolbar in a wrong way. I added my `onCreate()` code.

Comment: @juergend `onCreate()` looks fine too... Have you tried `android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"` (no "*attr*")?

Comment: I did. Same result.

Comment: Last try :) According to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33334185/toolbar-behind-status-bar-with-api-21 setting `CoordinatorLayout`'s `android:fitsSystemWindows` to **false** can help.

Comment: You are awesome. That's it. Please edit your answer accordingly.