# Android Toolbar minHeight redundant?

Tags: android, xml, toolbar

I built my Toolbar like in most with `minHeight` set to `actionBarSize`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

However, if I delete this attribute, there is no difference at all. The Toolbar keeps its `actionBarSize`, even if I remove the menu and set the app name to an empty `String`, so there is nothing displayed in the Toolbar at all.

Is there anything I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is completely intentional behaviour, The min height of `ToolBar` is set to action bar height by default . so yea `android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"` is redundunt . I couldn't find any official document on this but check out this tweet .

https://twitter.com/cyrilmottier/status/814465544279691266

Answer (score 2):

```
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

`minHeight` will ensure that your toolbar does not resize itself lower than `?attr/actionBarSize` not matter how small the content inside the `toolbar` is.

#### EDIT

If there is nothing inside a `toolbar` and if `minHeight` is not set, the `toolbar` will have a **default height** of `56dp` which is equal to `?attr/actionBarSize`

So setting `minHeight` for `toolbar` is redundant

For more details, [What's the height of the Android Toolbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30570904/whats-the-height-of-the-android-toolbar/30570905)

Comment: Yea that's the theory but even if my Toolbar is empty, it doesn't get smaller than actionBarSize even without the minHeight attribute. That's why I am wondering.

Answer (score 0):

On using both the attributes, `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` and `android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"`, there is a possibility that your toolbar height may get larger when you use larger icons.

`android:minHeight` ensures that your toolbar will not resize itself smaller than `?attr/actionBarSize` value.
If you want your toolbar height to be fixed, just use

`android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"`
The other attribute is not needed.

Comment: Can you give me a scenario when the Toolbar would get smaller than `actionBarSize`, because even if I remove every content from the Toolbar and remove the minHeight attribute, it never gets smaller then `actionBarSize`. So I wonder if its redundant.

Comment: its about getting larger if you use big icons. In context of Bigger icons. because it takes the default height if nothing specified

Answer (score 0):

Try this one I did like this it works for me:-

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


<LinearLayout
.......
/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```