# Get Exact Number of Recyclerview Items to fit the available screen height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am fetching results from the web to display it in the RecyclerView, in order to optimize the process, I wish to limit maximum results fetched from the web.

In order to limit the number of results, I need to know how many list items will be required to fill the entire screen. I have the height of each list item in dp, but I am not able to get the height of available space on screen so that I can divide screen height by height of each item (dp).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:id="@+id/video_list_layout"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     tools:context="com.bgbtech.gujaratirasoi.VideoListScreen">

     <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/video_list_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

So how to get the available height on the screen, excluding the actionbar

Comment: Use DisplayMetrics to get height of the screen & to get toolbar/actionbar height use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30570904/whats-the-height-of-the-android-toolbar/30570905. Then do device_height-appbar height to get remaining height or however you want to calculate your empty space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get screen size like this:

```
Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
int displayHeight = size.y;
```

You can get actionBar height like this

```
TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
getActivity().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize,typedValue, true);
int actionBarHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(typedValue.resourceId);
```